# Distinction between problems (such as equations), and universal truths

Tags: secondary-education, algebra, logic, language-use

How the distinction between problems (find/describe such values of *x* that… ) and universal truths (identities) is taught to secondary-school students and higher?
Especially in English-speaking countries.

Ī mean the following thing (sorry if Ī present an obvious stuff in a confused way): if we have a relation, equality or else, and a proposition with this relation at the top and some variable(s), then we have two distinct useful cases, although notation might be the same. In the first case the proposition *is not necessarily true* and we have to find values of the variable where it is true. In the second case the proposition [is necessarily true (law/identity/“theorem”)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/standard-word-for-a-formula-that-is-always-true) and variables become bound by universal quantification. Universal truths can be used in subsequent equivalent transformations of expressions, equations, inequalities, or something alike. Students *must learn to distinguish these cases,* haven’t they? **Examples:**

Binary **relations:**         “=”  (equals)     “>” (greater than)

**Problems:**   “$x^2 - x - 1 = 0$” (**equation**)   “$x^2 - x - 1 > 0$”

Universal **truths:**   “$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$”    “$\exp(x) > 0$”

```
How may be used: “α² = δ² ⇒ α = δ ∨ α = −δ ”      exp(α)⋅ℓ > 0 ⇔ ℓ > 0
          (transformed equation)       (transformed inequality (problem))
          “(α + 1)(α − 1) = α² − 1 ”       cosh α > 0
          (transformed expression)      (derived inequality (truth))
```

---

Why am Ī preoccupied with it? A year ago, the only person happened to [cooperate with me about precise equation–identity distinction in English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Equation#Identities) was a mathematician from France; was a coincidence he wasn’t taught in English? Today Ī argued on this topic (against two presumedly native English speakers) at a neighbouring site and become frustrated. Could an English speaker be correct in insisting that something like *a*<sup>*n*+1</sup> = *a* × *a*<sup>*n*</sup> is an “**equation**” and calling the “=” symbol in it “equation sign”?

Comment: I do see this as a very valid question, but I think you are not presenting it correctly.  The problem is not human language, the problem is the looseness in mathematical language.  I answered assuming this was for general education which I think is highly inappropriate.  However, this is _very_ appropriate to mathematical notations which affect both mathematicians and computer scientists.  I have always found mathematical proofs to be _too_ loose for my liking--there was never any overarching structure enforced.  This is a problem for computer scientists trying to study theorem proving.

Comment: And in an even broader sense I have seen that there is a wide range of notations across the mathematical disciplines (including mathematics, physics, computer science, etc.).  This includes not only mathematical notations but even terms used.  This is a real problem because it makes it difficult to communicate between the disciplines.

Answer (score 6):

I am comfortable saying "Solve the equation $x+2$=4" and also saying "Using the equation $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, we see that...".

On other other hand I would only ever speak of solving an equation, not an identity, and I would be willing to use the word "identity" in my second example above.

So I think I would say that an identity is a kind of equation, one which is universally quantified.

In general, one can avoid confusion jut by saying what you mean, as in "Solve the equation $x+2=4$", or "For all numbers $a$ and $b$, $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$"

Comment: Of course, boys and girls can be told about what does the teacher mean in each particular case. But how do they learn to understand the difference when they see a formula on a blackboard?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi What exactly are you hoping for?  I think, in general, people pick these things up from context, in exactly the same way they learn to distinguish the two uses of the word "lead" in "The lead developer on the project" and "The alchemist had finally succeeded in turning lead into gold".  Also, I think generally one should write "for each" on the board where it is appropriate.  Sometimes the extra symbols $\equiv$ or $:=$ can be helpful as well.

Comment: Your English-language example misses the point: notions are different and, AFAIK, words even are *pronounced* differently (note Ī rarely speak English IRL). No sane person would confuse “leader” and “Pb metal” internally, but there are morons (presumedly with academic degrees) who *ignore the problem–truth distinction*, unless they are carefully concealed trolls who argue that there is no such distinction in English language for fun.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi  I really do not appreciate this level of hostility.  You asked a question, and I am telling you that, as far as I know, there is no common English language distinction between "equality for a particular $x$" and "Equality for all $x$", unless you explicitly state that somehow.  If a student is given $x^2 = 4$ on a homework assignment, none of them will say "False:  $1^2 \neq 4$ is a counterexample".  Equality does have a meaning all on its own, after all.

Comment: Rereading your question in its entirety, your only real question appears to be "Could an English speaker be correct in insisting that something like $a^{n+1} = a \times a^n$ is an “equation” and calling the “=” symbol in it “equation sign”?".  The answer is "yes".  $a^{n+1} = a \times a^n$ is an equation since it asserts the equality of two quantities.

Comment: A bit better. Do you mean, a typical person educated in English language do not feel much linguistic difference between “equation”, “equality”, “(arithmetic) identity”?

Comment: I would say that an "equation" is any statement expressing equality of two expressions.  Both $x^2=1$ and $x(x)=x^2$ are equations, but they are (generally) quantified differently.  An identity is a specific kind of equation which is generally universally quantified somehow.  So $x(x)=x^2$ is an identity.  So it is okay to call $x(x)=x^2$ both an equation and an identity.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm from Poland, and Polish for "equation" (in the sense: something you solve for *x*) is "równanie".  Not only I'd *never* use this word for an identity, but if a student of mine called e.g. $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ a "równanie", I would correct his *erroneous* usage of the word.  (And I usually spend some time with first year students explaining how the innocently-looking equality sign can mean different things.)

Comment: @mbork: the only person intervened against the ignorant was a guy from Czech Republic, whereas Ī’m from Russia. Ī do not think this  “continental Europe vs Atlantic” thing was merely a coincidence; and it’s astonishing that England, once famous for its analytic philosophy, currently stands on the “ignorant” side.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I really recommend that you stop calling differences in language "ignorant".  Just because one language commonly distinguishes two things, and another doesn't, means nothing about the ability of people using those languages to distinguish the concepts!

Comment: Until some sources demonstrating that semantics of English “equation” is different from the one of our European *équation/równanie/уравнение* were provided, Ī prefer to blame Atlantic mathematical education for this “difference”. BTW, such countries as USA, England, and Australia routinely import mathematicians from around the globe.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Well, I am a mathematician in the USA, and I speak to a large number of mathematicians daily.  There does not appear to be a consistent verbal distinction between "equation true in a particular instance" and "equation true in all instances".  5 up-voters agree with me. Out of curiosity, do you have special words for equations with different quantification?  For example, is $\forall x \geq 0, \sqrt{x^2}=x$ an equation, an identity, or neither?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi No matter what the quantification, the equals sign asserts that the thing on the LHS "is the same" as the thing on the RHS.  From my perspective it is a benefit of English that we have only one name for this concept, since there is only one concept:  that of equality.  You can make different statements and ask different questions using this concept (like, "for which $x$ is it true that $x^2=4$" or "for all $x$, $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$"), but the meaning of the equals sign is the same in both cases.

Comment: You miss the point. One can write an “equation” $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, $x=x$, $0=0$, or whatever. Formally we should say solutions are $x≥0$, any $x$, and true (because no variables) respectively, but last two examples are trivial. Nobody **uses** them as an equation, unless as a reduction of some degenerate case. They are used only as identities. “$∀x≥0:\sqrt{x^2}=x$” is not an equation anyway because it is quantified and represents a fact (theorem, if you like) from real analysis, but “$\sqrt{x^2}=x$” is an equation yielding “$x\in[0,+∞)$” for real $x$ and not well-defined one for complex $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18264/discussion-between-steven-gubkin-and-incnis-mrsi).

Comment: @StevenGubkin Your example of $\forall x\geq 0, \sqrt{x^2} = x$ is not a good example (imo) because it shows that there is a serious problem in mathematics with notation.  The whole problem here is that an identity is a logical tautology (a theorem), but the assumptions must be stated, for instance, in gruesome detail your example should _really_ be written as such: $\forall x: \left(x\in \mathbb{R} \wedge x \geq 0\right)\rightarrow \sqrt{x^2} = x$, but we often use shorthand notation (such as you did) which does _not_ show the full logical formula.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (being taught in a US school), there is no explicit distinction between an identity and an equation.  The reason being is that to make the distinction you have to introduce first order logic which is not generally appropriate for secondary (high school) mathematics education.  Students can usually ascertain an identity (a formula) from an equation to be solved so this is not usually an issue.  The students that have trouble using formulas or have trouble solving equations are unlikely to benefit from a more detailed explanation (the detailed explanation will likely only further confuse them and make the topic of mathematics far less tangible and far more abstract).

**Examples:**

1. Quadratic equation.

We are generally taught that given $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ such that $a \neq 0$ that $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.  This is an identity.  It's a *first order* equation.  Formally it would state the following:

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{C}.\forall a, b, c\in \mathbb{R}:\left( \left(a\neq 0\wedge ax^2 + bx + c = 0\right) \rightarrow x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)
$$

2. Solving an equation:

Solve the following equation: $10x^2 + 6x + 8 = 0$ wher $x$ must be a real number.

The very first thing to do when solving an equation is to determine whether or not it *can* be solved.  This too is a first order logic equation.  The question (which must be answered) is whether or not the following is true:

$$
\exists x\in \mathbb{R}: 10x^2 + 6x + 8 = 0
$$

In this particular instance, the answer would be that the above is false therefore there are *no* solutions.  But how do you know that?  How do you prove that?

Here is a different example: Solve the following: $x^2 + 6x + 8 = 0$.  Again, we must first *decide* whether or not the following first order equation is true or false:

$$
\exists x\in \mathbb{R}: x^2 + 6x + 8 = 0
$$

In this case it is true (how do we know?).  Once we know the equation *can* be satisfied, we next attempt to find the particular solutions.  This is not easy and in fact, "impossible" in general.  Here is an example:

Find real values of $x$ that satisfy the following equation

$$
e^x = x + 2
$$

It can be *proved* that a solution exists:

$$
f(x) = e^x - x - 2 \rightarrow \text{find } f(x) = 0 \\
f'(x) = e^x - 1 \rightarrow f'(x) = 0 \rightarrow e^x = 1 \rightarrow x = \ln(1) = 0
$$

Since the derivative changes from negative to positive at $x = 0$, this represents a relative minimum (and since this is the *only* extrema this is the global minimum).  $f(0) = 1 - 0 - 2 = -1$.  Further since $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} e^x = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} = -\infty$ (thus subtracting negative infinity creates a positive infinity) and that $e^x$ dominates $-x$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} e^x - x = +\infty$, we *know* that this function, $f(x)$, goes towards $+\infty$ on either side, there *must* be two spots where $f(x) = 0$ and therefore there are *exactly* two real solutions to $e^x = x + 2$.

Yet even though we *know* the equation to be satisfiable, it is not clear how (or analytically possible) to solve for those two values.

So when solving equations there are two separate issues that we usually do *not* identify in secondary education (largely because it's beyond the scope).  The first is, whether or not there *is* a solution and the second is how to find the solution once you can show that one exists--note that the first step becomes tedious to the point of being prohibitive towards learning for the vast majority of problems encountered in elementary to high school level mathematics courses.

Comment: «⋯ = 1 − 0 − 2 = −2 ». ORLY?

Comment: By the way, to prove *no more than* two real solutions you have to make some more analysis beyond differentiability and limits.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi _"By the way, to prove no more than two real solutions you have to make some more analysis beyond differentiability and limits."_  If the function is continuous over all of the reals (which it is) and has only a single (real) critical point (which it does) and we know that the function ends up at $+ \infty$ on both sides, then the fact that its absolute minimum is $-2$ means that it _must_ cross the x-axis to the left _and_ to the right of that critical point.  Further, since there are no other (real) critical points, it could not possibly turn back around towards the x-axis.

Comment: The fact that its absolute minimum is −2 means that it’s easier to count extrema of a *C¹* function than perform two arithmetic operations on integers ☺

Comment: The mistake in elementary arithmetic [was not fixed for two days](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/posts/5668/revisions), so author’s deviation from the correct value of $f(0)$ is added to the score of the posting.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Wow, so you're faulting me because I said $1 - 0 - 2 = -2 \neq -1$ which changes nothing about my logic or the question at hand.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I made the correction to my answer--it required me changing a single character.